# Flutter FutureBuilder: type 'Response' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, http, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm trying to use flutter's `FutureBuilder` with an `http.get()` as the future parameter like so:

```
child: FutureBuilder(
  future: http.get(
      Uri.http('192.168.31.144:8000', 'api/v1/login')),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState ==
        ConnectionState.done) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text('error');
      }
      return Text(snapshot.data);
    } else {
      return SpinKitFadingCircle(color: Colors.white);
    }
  },
),
```

I get the following error:
`The following _TypeError was thrown building FutureBuilder<Response>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<Response>#0caa6): type 'Response' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

From what I understand is that the FutureBuilder needs type `Future<Response>` as its future but `http.get()` is returning type `String`?

Answer (score 0):

you have yo await for your future to come

```
Future<dynamic> getData() async {
return await http.get(Uri.http('192.168.31.144:8000', 'api/v1/login');
}



 child: FutureBuilder(
      future: getData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState ==
            ConnectionState.done) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('error');
          }
          return Text(snapshot.data);
        } else {
          return SpinKitFadingCircle(color: Colors.white);
        }
      },
    ),
```

Comment: I've tried this. It causes another 2 errors:
1 
`The argument type 'Response' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<dynamic>'`
2
`The await expression can only be used in an async function.
Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*'`

Comment: I've edited the answer , add the function to your class and try now

Comment: No need to await with a FutureBuilder!  It essentially does that automatically on the future: parameter.  But you have a different issue, because you're creating the Future on each call to build(), and that's problematic, as illustrated here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg